# "floors curving upward" vs. "floors that curved upward"

Tags: grammar

Is the phrase "18th century wagons had floors curving upward" grammatically correct?

Does curving need to be a different tense? Why or why not?

Comment: I would accept "floors curving upward", "floors that curved upward", and even "upcurving floors". The middle one would be my preference, though. :-)

Comment: You need to read up on participles. This is basic English.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that *'bowed'* or *'bowing'* might be terms equally likely encountered when talking about wagon construction, along with *'curving'* , *'curved'* and *'upcurved'*.  As EL&U member JEL points out, all usages are interchangeable.  But it also has to be said that the most common expression used in those times for the *'floor'* of the wagon (and since by those who keep or restore horse or bullock drawn wagons) is actually *'wagon bed'*.

[image]

*'Bowing'* (or *'curving'*) of the bed of the wagon may have had something to do with stabilising loads, as suggested in this image of a Conestoga wagon:

[image]

The Conestoga wagon was primarily used for carrying heavy cargo, as this Wikipedia article explains: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conestoga_wagon

In the case of some passenger wagons (what we might call stage-coaches'), the coach body actually rested on leather straps, known as 'through-braces'. The curved bed of the coach body in this design was simply conforming to the curve in the flexible straps supporting the weight of the coach.  The straps provided an effective shock absorber - essential in the days of solid wheels and unpaved roads.  This image shows the coach body, bed and through-braces:

[image]

The expression *'bed'* that came from wagon and coach design has continued in some car designs, for example:

[image]

The expression *'bed'* has also continued in respect of some truck and and railway wagons as explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatbed_truck.